# Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session issue with appium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, appium

Since I'm new to mobile automation, I've been trying to run simple activities using appium maven and eclipse. But When I try to run Calculator app opens but the elements are not accessible.

This the code I used to run a simple calculator

```
  @BeforeClass
 public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "4.4.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void testCal() throws Exception {

    WebElement two = driver.findElement(By.name("2"));
    two.click();

}

@AfterClass
public void teardown() {

}
```

**I am using the latest stable dependencies.**
    io.appium java-client 7.0.0 and 
org.testng testng 6.14.3

```
FAILED: testCal
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Locator Strategy 'css 
selector' is not supported for this session
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {BROWSER_NAME: Android, VERSION: 4.4.2, appActivity: 
com.android.calculator2.Cal..., appPackage: com.android.calculator2, 
databaseEnabled: false, desired: {BROWSER_NAME: Android, VERSION: 4.4.2, 
appActivity: com.android.calculator2.Cal..., appPackage: 
com.android.calculator2, deviceName: Emulator, platformName: android}, 
deviceManufacturer: HUAWEI, deviceModel: FLA-LX2, deviceName: 
HXT7N18521000819, deviceScreenSize: 1080x2160, deviceUDID: 
HXT7N18521000819, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, 
networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, 
platformVersion: 8.0.0, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, 
webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: a604a166-3c0d-4e9c-a3e4-9b1ea734bee6
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=2}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown 
Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at...
```

Answer (score 6):

Appium is not Selenium: they both implemented using JSON wire protocol and has similar APIs, but not the same ones:

Supported locator strategies for Native android app:

- id (resource-id View attribute);
- accessbilityId (content-desc View attribute);
- uiAutomator (better to read about [UiSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html));
- className (ui component type);
- XPath.

So you cannot use `By.name` locator strategy for Android driver session, it's not supported.

To make it easy, I suggest using `MobileBy` in place of `By` in Appium native tests: you will get the proper options.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this approach on feb 3rd 2020 and was able to execute succesfully. The change I had to make are update io.appium to 7.2.0.

Pre Requisites in my Case/test: Windows Machine, created Nexus S AVD, Launched Appium and AVD.

Most Importantly

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, capabilities);
MobileElement two =(MobileElement)driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_9"));   
two.click();
```

Comment: I'm trying to test the Hybrid Mobile application written with Ionic. Do you have any suggestions on that ? I have tried switching the context to web, but I'm stuck with that too.

Answer (score 1):

`By.name("text")` is removed from `Appium v1.5.0` onwards.

Also just to add `cssSelector` strategy + methods like `getAttribute("color/background")` present in Selenium are not supported in Appium for native apps as these are not supported by underlying unit testing framework of Android i.e. `UIAutomator`.

You can use below options for clicking digits of calculator

```
driver.findElement(By.id(“com.android.calculator2:id/digit5”)).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'digit5') and @text='5']”)).click();
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(“plus”).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//android.widget.Button[@text='5']”)).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use Class name and text name to create a xpath.

```
const loginbutton=await driver.$("//android.widget.TextView[@text='login']")


await loginbutton.click()
```

Driver comes from capabilities

`class name --> android.widget.TextView`

`text name -->login`

so always use class name and text name to create a better and nicer xpath.

works for all android+appium+wdio

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got this issue too. If anyone wants to know, here are the things i did to solve this issue.

1. Updated the java-client. I updated it to version 7.2.0 in the pom.
2. Removed the selenium-java dependency. This is needed to be removed, as java-client already has the selenium dependency.If not removed it might cause conflict.
3. Update my maven project.
4. Rerun the test. I just tried to click the number 5 in the calculator app using an emulator, and it worked

[image]

Comment: If you removed selenium-java dependencies, then how did you use DesiredCapabilities? Could you share your code and also the pom.xml file please?