# return self.find_element (by = By.ID, value = id_) and exception errors in Python appium

Tags: python, appium

I want to write automation test in python. I'm using an android studio emulator and appium. I want to write automation for the calculator, but somewhere there has been an error.

I added time.sleep() but the problem still continues.

```
from appium import webdriver

import time

caps = {"deviceName": "emulator-5554", "platformName": "android", "appPackage": "com.android.calculator2",
        "appActivity": ".Calculator", "noReset": True}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", caps)

el2 = driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_8")

el2.click()

time.sleep(2)

el3 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("times")

el3.click()

time.sleep(2)

el4 = driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_3")

el4.click()

time.sleep(2)

el5 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("equals")

el5.click()

time.sleep(2)

el6 = driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.calculator2:id/formula")

el6.click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

I'm waiting for the android emulator to open and calculate.

I have this error lines;

```
> C:\python37\dersler1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:/python37/dersler1/hs.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/python37/dersler1/hs.py", line 12, in <module>
>     el2 = driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_8")   File
> "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 360, in find_element_by_id
>     return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)   File "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 978, in find_element
>     'value': value})['value']   File "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py",
> line 29, in check_response
>     raise wde   File "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py",
> line 24, in check_response
>     super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)   File "C:\python37\dersler1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Locator
> Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session issue with appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861110/locator-strategy-css-selector-is-not-supported-for-this-session-issue-with-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from appium import webdriver
import time

PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p))
desired_caps = {
    "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
    "platformName": "android",
    "appPackage": "com.android.calculator2",
    "appActivity": ".Calculator",
    "noReset": True
}
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)

while True:
    try:
        el1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.Button[6]')
        el1.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        el2 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("times")
        el2.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        el3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath( 
'/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.Button[9]')
        el3.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        el4 = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("equals")
        el4.click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except ValueError:
        print(" ERROR BRO  ")
        pass
    break
```

> Some ids are working, others are not. I used xpath instead of id and
>   the error improved. I think the number of ids is constantly changing.
>   Xpath helped.

Answer (score 0):

@adem I think your version of `Appium-Python-Client` is outdated and it is not compatible with your current `Appium server` version.
Update your `Appium-Python-Client` with command **sudo pip install Appium-Python-Client==0.34**

I also faced the same issue some times back. As I can see you have not used **css_selector** anywhere in your script but still it is showing the error of css_selector. When you check in your `Appium logs` you will get more idea about it.

For me, it solved when I update my **Appium-Python-Client** version to 0.34

Comment: Thanks Sachhya for this info. I think my versions are up to date. there seemed to be a problem with id. Xpath helped me with this problem. I usually prefer "xpath" in appium now. Because sometimes accessibility_id or by_id doesn't give full result. What do you think about this topic ?

Comment: I don't think so, if resource-id is present there then it must be accessible.

Comment: One more thing you are getting error related to css_ selector which is not present anywhere in your script. I Know using `xpath` is an option but that not means you can not access that by id.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm what is the version of your appium server and appium Python client.

Comment: My appium-python-client version =>  0.47    Appium Server  => 1.13.0